# angularfire2 - getting an array of tags

Tags: javascript, tags, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to get an array of tags to print the tags correctly in my template.  I have this:

```
<div *ngFor="let tweet of tweets | async">

    <p>
    {{ tweet.msg}}
    </p>
    <p>
    {{ tweet.username }}
    </p>
    Tags:
    <div *ngFor="let tag of tweet.tags">
        {{ tag }}
    </div>

</div>
```

My firestore database is like this for index reasons:

```
tweets: { 
  msg: "joe", 
  username: "bill2", 
  tags: {
    construction: true,
    computers: true
  }
}
```

Everything prints correctly except the tags.

I am thinking something like this, but then I fail.

```
this.tweetsCollection = this.afs.collection('tweets');
this.tweets = this.tweetsCollection.valueChanges();
this.tweets.subscribe(tags => {
  tags.forEach(tag => {
    Object.keys(tag).map(key => tag[key])
})
```

This obviously does not work. Is that even necessary? I think I am overthinking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out

```
this.tweetsCollection = this.afs.collection('tweets');
this.tweets = this.tweetsCollection.valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    tap(tweets => {

      tweets.forEach(tweet => {

        tweet['tags'] = tweet['tags'] ? tweet['tags'] : {}

        let tags = [];

        Object.keys(tweet['tags']).forEach(tag => {
          tags.push(tag);

        })

        tweet['tags_list'] = tags;
      })
    })
  )
```

It was several things. I can't overwrite the "tags" array, I had to create a new one: "tags_list".  Also, you can't subscribe right after value changes without a do() in angular < 5 or a pipe(tap()) in angular 6. Last but not least, thanks to Jeremy W and Troy Myers, I now grabbed the keys correctly. It also updates the tags asynchronously which is great. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `tags` property is an object. `*ngFor` needs an array to loop over, so you need to turn the `tags` property into an array.

```
this.tweetsCollection = this.afs.collection('tweets');
this.tweets = this.tweetsCollection.valueChanges();
this.tweets.subscribe(arrayOfTweets => {
  arrayOfTweets.forEach(eachTweet => {
    // Ensure we don't get an undefined error if there is no 'tags' property on this tweet
    eachTweet['tags'] = eachTweet['tags'] ? eachTweet['tags'] : {}
    // Prepare HTML-friendly array of tags
    let arrayOfTags = [];
    // Loop over the 'tags' object's properties, we're interested in saving the name of the key of the property
    Object.keys(eachTweet['tags']).forEach(eachTagName => {
      arrayOfTags.push(eachTagName);
    })
    // Finally, overwrite the 'tags' property...
    eachTweet['tags'] = arrayOfTags;
  })
})
```

Comment: I am trying to debug it, but the tags will not change.  I believe the valueChanges() - the point of using async, keeping it from updating... will get back to you if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you are looking for:

```
  tweet_list = [];

  this.tweetsCollection = this.afs.collection('tweets');

  this.tweets = this.tweetsCollection.valueChanges();

  this.tweets.subscribe(tweet_collection => {

  tweet_collection.forEach(tweet => {

  let tweetElement = tweet;

  tweetElement.tags = Object.keys(tweetElement.tags);

  this.tweet_list.push(tweetElement);

});

});
```

You need to change the the 'tags' object returned by Firebase into an array to be able to use *ngFor and that was done by this bit:

`Object.keys(tweetElement.tags);`

Comment: this does not work, I get issues with putting subscribe after valuechanges()